# Replace subsequent values with NA if prior values max possible value on separate column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataset where each row represents a new test taken by individuals. It has four variables.

1) IDs of the test takers:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

2) Dates the individuals took the test:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2007-06-22", "2008-06-21", "2009-06-22", "2008-06-21", "2009-06-22"))
```

3) Scores they received on that test:

```
scores <- c(0, 12, 12, 1, 3)
```

4) Whether or not that score was the best score of the individual up to that time point.

```
improvement <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")
```

So the dataset is:

```
df <- data.frame(id, dates, scores, improvement) 

  id      dates scores improvement
1  1 2007-06-22      0          No
2  1 2008-06-21     12         Yes
3  1 2009-06-22     12          No
4  2 2008-06-21      1          No
5  2 2009-06-22      3         Yes
```

I've got a problem though. A score of 12 is the highest. So if someone gets a 12, there would be no more room for improvement. Do you know how I could make it so that when someone gets a 12, on any subsequent rows they get NA on improvement?

i.e.,

```
   id      dates scores improvement
 1  1 2007-06-22      0          No
 2  1 2008-06-21     12         Yes
 3  1 2009-06-22     12          NA
 4  2 2008-06-21      1          No
 5  2 2009-06-22      3         Yes
```

Comment: Please show the desired result and what you have tried.

Comment: @Rich Scriven  I think the question and expected output were clearly explained in words, though not shown as code/image.

Comment: I don't think it's clear.  Are we grouping by ID?  So the first 12 remains and every 12 afterward becomes NA, by ID?

Comment: But in the context of the problem--"improvement"--it would make sense. I would agree with you if this were just a generic data frame without context.

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks for your suggestion. I added desired result. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'id', `order` the 'id' and 'dates', get the logical index for maximum scores (`scores == max(scores)`), find the cumulative sum (`cumsum(...)`), convert it to a logical `vector` (`>1`) and get the row index (`.I`).  Specify the row index in `i` and assign (`:=`) the elements in 'improvement' that corresponds to that index to `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[order(id, dates), .I[cumsum(scores == max(scores))>1], 
                             by = id]$V1, improvement := NA]
df
#    id      dates scores improvement
#1:  1 2007-06-22      0          No
#2:  1 2008-06-21     12         Yes
#3:  1 2009-06-22     12          NA
#4:  2 2008-06-21      1          No
#5:  2 2009-06-22      3         Yes
```

#### Update

If the max values are not adjacent, either we can `order` by 'scores' as well or another option is

```
setDT(df1)[df1[order(id, dates), .I[cumsum(scores == max(scores))>1 & 
               scores ==max(scores)], by = id]$V1, improvement := NA]
df1
#     id      dates scores improvement
#1:  1 2007-06-22      0          No
#2:  1 2008-06-21     12         Yes
#3:  1 2009-06-22      5          No
#4:  1 2010-06-21     12          NA
#5:  2 2008-06-21      1          No
#6:  2 2009-06-22      3         Yes
```

A slight improvement to the above is to call the `scores==max(scores)` one time by creating an object

```
setDT(df1)[df1[order(id, dates), {mx <- scores == max(scores)
                              .I[cumsum(mx)>1 & mx]},  
                      by = id]$V1, improvement := NA]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), dates = structure(c(13686, 
14051, 14417, 14781, 14051, 14417), class = "Date"), scores = c(0, 
12, 5, 12, 1, 3), improvement = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"dates", "scores", "improvement"), row.names = c(NA, -6L),
 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This seems to work! Also, thank you for the detailed explanation. Cheers!

Comment: I think this will fail if the second score of 12 for a given `id` doesn't come immediately after the first score of 12, because the value of `improvement` between the first 12 and the second 12 will not be set to `NA`.

Comment: @akrun. Sorry for the confusion. I unchecked it because it seems like it is  putting in NAs for any repeated max scores. E.g., if someone's max score was 4, then they got an NA on subsequent 4s. But I think if I replace "scores == max(scores)" in your code with 12, it should work. In a sec, I'm going to look into eipi10's comment too. Maybe he/she has a point.

Answer (score 3):

How about this: We use `dplyr` to group by `id`, then for each `id` we check whether any score is equal to 12. If so, then we replace every value of `improvement` with `NA` in subsequent rows after the first instance of a score of 12.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(id, dates) %>%
  mutate(improvement = replace(improvement, if(any(scores==12)) (min(which(scores==12))+1):n(), NA))
```

> ```
>      id      dates scores improvement
>   <dbl>     <date>  <dbl>      <fctr>
> 1     1 2007-06-22      0          No
> 2     1 2008-06-21     12         Yes
> 3     1 2009-06-22     12          NA
> 4     2 2008-06-21      1          No
> 5     2 2009-06-22      3         Yes
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your help eipi10! I liked your answer because I understood it and it was fast. 

 I ran into a weird error though. If I just changed one of the ids like this: 

    df$id[3] <- 3

Then when I run your code, I got this error:

    Error: incompatible size.

I couldn't figure out why. All good though. @akrun 's code worked.

Comment: Yes, my answer fails if there's only one row for a given `id`. I'll fix that in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

the operation can also be done just using the base package. Though it is bit messy, it creates opportunity for people who aren't familiar with the `dplyr` package, etc. Here is the code and I have explained my logic as comments in the code:

```
## Note: you cannot have factor levels in the `improvement` column
df$id <- as.character(df$id) ##IMPORTANT
df$improvement <- as.character(df$improvement) ##really important


new_df <- NULL #new data frame; placeholder for now
for(test_taker in unique(df$id)) {

  ## Sub-dataframe for each individual's record:
  sub_df <- df[df$id == test_taker, ]

  ## For each individual's record, look for score of 12
  ## If there is such a score that occur more than once
  ## change the second score of 12 and beyond to NA 
  indices <- which(df$scores[df$id == test_taker] %in% c(12))
  if(sum(indices) > 1) {
    sub_df[indices[2:length(indices)], "improvement"] <-NA
  }

  ## Update the new data.frame
  new_df <- rbind(new_df,  sub_df)
}
new_df

   ##    id      dates scores improvement
   ##  1  1 2007-06-22      0          No
   ##  2  1 2008-06-21     12         Yes
   ##  3  1 2009-06-22     12        <NA>
   ##  4  2 2008-06-21      1          No
   ##  5  2 2009-06-22      3         Yes
```

Comment: I ended up using @akrun 's solution because it was faster. But thank you for your suggestion!